# Java objects instead of lookup in database

Tags: java, dictionary, lookup, records

I need insert many rows from many files like:

```
Identifier NumberValue
```

For each row I am looing if already exists in database row with Identifier, if exists I will take its NumberValue and add NumberValue from arriving row and update database.
I have found that lookup in database for each row (few millions of records total) takes many time.
Does it make sense create map and look before inserting in database in this map?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this a sql question?

Comment: it is private database. The sense of question evitate lookup in database.

Comment: One lookup isn't very expensive. What is expensive is doing it row for row. There's surely a way to optimize the insert statement so you can do WAY less lookups.

Comment: I should do lookup for each row. But... If I already found - I could save in a map and so don't do next search.

Answer (score 1):

I would get the value, add one hundred rows, and add one hundred to the `NumberValue` in a single transaction.

Comment: The problem not in insert. It already done in single transaction for many rows. The sense of question is make lookup more quick - create some construction, because there is no need full database for lookup

Comment: My suggestion is to do less lookups.  You only need to do one lookup and one update per batch.  If you do this, it doesn't matter how long it takes.

Comment: Why is that?  If the first one is 1000, is not the second one 1001, then 1002 etc.

Comment: because database doesn't supporta update many rows in one time. It support only update 1 row or insert many rows.

Comment: Can you add 1000 to the counter, and then insert 1000 rows as two operations?

Comment: If you did the lookup 1/1000th of the time you do now, wouldn't that be faster?

Comment: Thanks. Good point - I will measure time used lookup and for insert

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Index to the column you are searching on if it's not the Primary Key by using

```
@Table(indexes = { @Index( columnList = ".." ) })
```

Comment: it is not question about database optimization

Comment: "I have found that lookup in database for each row (few millions of records total) takes many time." ~OP. That sounds like asking for ways to make the lookup faster to me, and the easiest solution is to optimize the database. Using a map will only help you if you had the entire table in memory anyway. How you manipulate the data on the application side will not change the lookup time.

Comment: Thanks. Good point - I will measure time used lookup and for insert

Answer (score 1):

So basically you're asking if it will be faster to check an in memory map of your entire database in order to potentially save the transaction cost of looking up if something exists, and if not, performing an insert to the database?

The answer of course is "maybe".  Despite what you dont want to hear, it really is going to depend on the details of the database that you havent explained to us.

- Is it a local one with fast access or perhaps something that's remotely accessed overseas across slow lines.
- Are you running on a hefty machine where the amount of memory use really isn't an issue (else you'll end up swapping).
- Does the database have indexes and primary keys in place that can quickly search and reject entries if they are duplicates?
- Are these running on one server or does each server need to update what was saved to the DB to keep this in memory cache concurrent?

In general, the in memory map will make things work faster.  But as I'm sure others can point out, there are a lot of issues and exceptions you'll have to deal with.  Reading in a million rows in one go is probably faster than reading in a million rows one at a time in order to check if that particular identifier exists, but again, it really depends on the balance between quantity and resources and time available.

How's that for a non-answer...